# Population Covariance Calculation with ddof parameter for DataFrame.cov() in Python

Tags: python, dataframe, covariance

I have a dataframe with stock prices.(actually its a excel with 2600 rows. My problem is when creating the covariance matrix, the ddof parameter in dataframe.cov has a value of 1 by default. This corresponds to the sample covariance method. However, I want to create a covar with the method of population, namely /N. I have tried =df1.cov(ddof=0) but it had no effect.

Can you help me to create a dataframe.cov with the bias true, that is, the population method? Or can you organize my code according to numpy.cov?

Thank you,

My dataframe; (dfr)

| Date | Code | Price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 28.02.2022 | A | 55 |
| 25.02.2022 | A | 55.1 |
| 24.02.2022 | A | 54 |
| 23.02.2022 | A | 54.2 |
| 22.02.2022 | A | 56.112 |
| 21.02.2022 | A | 56 |
| 28.02.2022 | B | 5 |
| 25.02.2022 | B | 4 |
| 24.02.2022 | B | 4 |
| 23.02.2022 | B | 4.2 |
| 22.02.2022 | B | 5.1 |
| 21.02.2022 | B | 5 |
| 28.02.2022 | C | 7 |
| 25.02.2022 | C | 7.2 |
| 24.02.2022 | C | 7 |
| 23.02.2022 | C | 8 |
| 22.02.2022 | C | 6.9 |
| 21.02.2022 | C | 7 |

My code;

```
dfr = dfr.set_index(['Date', 'Code']).Price.unstack(['Code'])
df1 = dfr.pct_change()
df1.to_excel(r'C:\sample\df1.xlsx', index = True)  

#Covar
df2 = df1.cov()
df2.to_excel(r'C:\sample\df2.xlsx', index = True)
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]I am not sure what you mean you are not getting with ddof=0? I get the differences.

---

ddoftest=pd.read_csv("ddoftest.csv")
covar=ddoftest.cov()
print(covar)
covar1=ddoftest.cov(ddof=0)
print(covar1)

---

```
      A         B         C
```

A  0.060795 -0.007887 -0.018725
B -0.007887  0.092322  0.022308
C -0.018725  0.022308  0.075867
A         B         C
A  0.057418 -0.007448 -0.017685
B -0.007448  0.087193  0.021068
C -0.017685  0.021068  0.071652

---

I chose A, B and C as some random stock prices

Comment: Having ddof 1 or 0 in dataframe.cov has no effect. You will get the same result whether you do it with ddof 1 or ddof 0. So my question is, how can I use dataframe.cov with ddof 0

Comment: If I do it in ddof 0, it is the same if I do it in ddof 1.

Comment: I am sorry but i do not understand. Please see code above. When I change the degrees of freedom to 0 , i,e,, for population, my covariance matrix changes as displayed. Now what effect are you expecting?

Comment: Did you format your dates to datetimes? That might have unintended effects.

Comment: Can you get the returns of the prices with pct_change? You did the covariance matrix directly with prices. You should use Price.pct_change

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: if you take the pct_change of the prices and apply ddof 0 you will see that the result will not change.

Comment: Your problem may be of statistical nature? If not (i.e., if there is a bug in pandas method?) , then I recommend you write your own cov matrix method. Should be straightforward.